# Teamcity - How to set credentials for package source

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, build-agent, teamcity-9.1

I am using TeamCity to build my .net application. One of the build step connects to a Nuget package repository and try to restore nuget packages. During this step, I am seeing `returned an unexpected status code '401 Unauthorized` error while system try to restore nuget package from a specific repository.

How can I set the credentials so that TeamCity server picks it up and pass it while accessing repository.

Answer (score 3):

Looking to the left of the build step's form-fields, under **Build Configuration** Settings is **Build Features**.

then

On the left, click on **Build Features**.

Click on the **Add build feature** button.

select `NuGet Feed Credentials`.

For Feed URI, enter the URL, uid and pwd